# Глобальные переменные в react и доступ к ним

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Начал изучать реакт и столкнулся с ситуацией, которую не понимаю в принципе, но очень хочу понять: как в react организовано "слушание" глобальных переменных, которые доступны всем классам в рамках одного приложения или скрипта?

Приведу пример на псевдокоде:

```
var a = false;

var globalVariable = function(e) {
    a = e.target.value;
}

var ExampleClassA = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: functuion () {
       return {
          globalAccess: false
       }
    }

    render: function() {
       return (
           <div>
              <input type='checkbox' onChange={globalVariable.bind(this)}/>
           </div>
       )
    }
})

var ExampleClassB = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      return (
          <span>{то, что поможет как-нибудь получить значение a}</span>
      )
   }
})
```

Конечно, тут может быть масса ошибок, но картина в принципе ясна.

Comment: В коде нет ничего из сформулированного вопроса. А ещё надо бы различать значения и функции.

Comment: @Qwertiy я настолько не могу понять то, как это сделать, что не могу нормально сформулировать. Немного изменил, но не думаю, что общая концепция "неправильности" изменилась. Простите, что увы так :(

Comment: Сделай [работоспособный сниппет](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536762/178988).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы в `ExampleClassB` обнаружить изменение переменной `a`, нужно оба компонента встроить в общий родительский компонент, где переменная `a` будет уже членом объекта состояния родительского компонента, в компонент `ExampleClassB` передавать через свойства. Родительский метод для изменения переменной так же необходимо передать через свойство в компонент `ExampleClassA`.

Примерный код:

```
var ExampleClassA = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type='checkbox' onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var ExampleClassB = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <span>{this.props.a? "true" : "false"}</span>
        );
    }
});

var ParentClass = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            a: false
        };
    },

    changeVariable(e) {
        this.setState({a: e.target.checked});
    },


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <ExampleClassA onChange={this.changeVariable} />
                <ExampleClassB a={this.state.a} />
            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

Работоспособность можно проверить тут: https://jsfiddle.net/szepej8o/

Comment: Да, уже давненько разобрался с этим вопросом, спасибо :)